# range.copy Destination "A1" vs "Cells(1,1)" Excel/VBA

Tags: excel, syntax, copy-paste, vba

Consider the below:

```
    Sheets("X").Activate
    Sheets("X").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 30)).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Y").Range("A1") 'Syntax 1
    Sheets("X").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 30)).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Y").Range(Cells(1, 1)) 'Syntax 2
```

Why does Syntax 1 works while Syntax 2 runs into 'Application-defined or object-defined error'?

Comment: Range is either a string or two cells marking the extents of the range.  You could do `Sheets("Y").Range(Sheets("Y").Cells(1, 1).Address(0,0))` to return a string.  But you cannot denote a range of one cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unqualified `Cells(1,1)` belongs to the ActiveSheet, which is currently Sheets("X"), so it does not belong to `Sheets("Y")`.

OTOH: this should work:

```
Destination:=Sheets("Y").Range(Sheets("Y").Cells(1, 1), Sheets("Y").Cells(1, 1)) 
'                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Dont use unqualified  ranges. Drop the `Activate` stuf altogether from your code.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't qualified the sheet name.  So the copy happens on the ActiveSheet it then tries to reference Cell(1,1) from the ActiveSheet but on sheet Y:

`Sheets("Y").Range(Cells(1, 1))`

Sheets("Y") is sheet Y.
Cells(1,1) is the ActiveSheet.

The copy only works because you activate sheet X first.  Remove that line, select another sheet and it will fail on that as well.

Comment: 'The copy only works because you activate sheet X first.' I'm quite puzzled since I activate sheet "X" and "A1" refers (and works!) on sheet "Y". Any idea if Microsoft publishes any documentation that explains how this works on the background?

Comment: Yes, `Sheets("Y").Range("A1")` works as it refers to A1 on Sheet Y - it's all one reference.   `Sheets("X").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 30))` uses three references - `Sheets("X").Range(` references Sheet X while `Cells(1, 1)` and `Cells(1, 30)` reference the ActiveSheet.  To get those to reference Sheet X as well you'd write `Sheets("X").Range(Sheets("X").Cells(1, 1), Sheets("X").Cells(1, 30))` - but then it will look at the active workbook so you need to qualify that as well - `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("X").Range(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("X").Cells(1, 1), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("X").Cells(1, 30))`

Comment: That last bit of code in my previous comment gets very clunky - which is why there's `With...End With` blocks.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb(v=vs.90).aspx or using variables: `Set wrkSht = ThisWorbook.Worksheets(X)` and `wrksht.Range(wrksht.Cells(1, 1), wrksht.Cells(1, 30))`